# python process multiple string at the same time

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings and i want to remove the stop words inside each string. The thing is, the length of the stopwords is much longer than the strings and I don't want to repeat comparing each string with the stopwords list. Is there a way in python that these multiple strings at the same time?

```
lis = ['aka', 'this is a good day', 'a pretty dog']
stopwords = [] # pretty long list of words
for phrase in lis:
    phrase = phrase.split(' ') # get list of words
    for word in phrase:
        if stopwords.contain(word):
            phrase.replace(word, '')
```

This is my current method. But these means I have to go through all the phrases in the list. Is there a way that I can process these phrases with only one time compare?

Thanks.

Comment: How long is "long"? If it's less than 100,000 elements, I wouldn't worry about it. Especially if you make `stopwords` into a set, as `x in set` checking is very fast.

Comment: a nested list comprehension statement would maybe be nicer(or more confusing? ) to look at, but this is pretty much the best way i can see to do this

Comment: @Kevin Well, it's 100, 000 long but still don't want to check like multiple times..

Comment: you have to check if each phrase has to be checked and as kevin said using a set would make lookups `0(1)`

Comment: [Some complexity comparisons](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) show that checking for `x in stopwords` is linear in time if `stopwords` is a list and constant in time if it is a set (as Kevin said). In other words, with a set, you (almost) wouldn't feel the difference between a little one and a huge one (it's fast in both case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same idea, but with a few improvements. Convert your `list` of stopwords to a `set` for faster lookups. Then you can iterate over your phrase list in a list comprehension. You can then iterate over the words in the phrase, and keep them if they're not in the stop set, then `join` the phrase back together.

```
>>> lis = ['aka', 'this is a good day', 'a pretty dog']
>>> stopwords = ['a', 'dog']
>>> stop = set(stopwords)
>>> [' '.join(j for j in i.split(' ') if j not in stop) for i in lis]
['aka', 'this is good day', 'pretty']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the difference between the list formed by each phrase and the stop words.

```
>>> lis = ['aka', 'this is a good day', 'a pretty dog']
>>> stopwords = ['a', 'dog']

>>> stop = set(stopwords)
>>> result = map(lambda phrase: " ".join(list( set(phrase.split(' ')) - stop)), lis)
>>> print( result )

['aka', 'this is good day', 'pretty']
```

Comment: That actually messes up the order of the words in the phrases since you make a set out the split. with `lis = ['a b c d e f g']` it gives `['c b e d g f']`.